# Schengen visa - explanatory statement needed?

Tags: visas, schengen

My parents - Indian passport holders - are planning to travel to the Czech Republic in May. My dad has a Polish Schengen visa issued for a work trip to Poland and will be using this visa. My mother is going to apply for a Czech visa. As my mom is applying alone, my dad is sending a statement with her application, stating that he is financially supporting the trip and that he has a valid visa. As it is a Poland-issued visa, does he need to explain why he has a Polish visa and how he got it?

Thanks,
Ansh

Comment: He doesn't even have to say that he has a visa.

Comment: @Neusser, it is a bad idea to leave the visa officials puzzled. He should state that they're traveling together and that he doesn't need a visa because he has one.

Comment: Just confirm he has been to Poland already? They will question him if he first uses the visa in Czech, before going to Poland.

Comment: Yes, he has travelled to Poland. Entry and exit from FRA though. I have told him to write in his support letter that he is using a Polish visa issued previously for work, and he has travelled to Poland already.

Comment: @o.m. you should post that as an answer and [claim the bounty](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/bounty)!

Comment: @phoog, I just did it. Not that the points will make much difference.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bad idea to leave the visa officials puzzled. He should state that they're traveling together and that he doesn't need a visa because he has one.